# Linq to SQL Class - Stored Procedure Signature Change

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a Linq to Sql .dbml file which auto generates my method signatures for certain stored procedures. eg, I have in SQL `spGetEmployees(@Name)` so in my data context I have `spGetEmployees(string Name)`.

Now, my underlying sp changed to add an additional parameter: `spGetEmployees(@name, @count)` and so I want the function in my `DataContext` to change as well. Is there a way to do this without dropping the stored proc from the Linq to Sql class file and re-adding it?

Comment: There is a very similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345227/problem-refreshing-tables-in-the-linq-to-sql-designer

Answer (score 4):

Currently if you use the ui you must drop the function and add it back there is no refresh yet.  You can automate this class with sqlmetal.exe this will allow you to regenerate these files every time you update your database.

Answer (score 2):

There is a third-party tool that does this available from http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/